# How to get statistics of CPU throttling?

Tags: cpu, cron, cpu-usage, throttling, cpu-throttling

My dmesg output says that the CPUs are throttled, because of the temperature.

```
[ 1283.260276] CPU3: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 1283.260277] CPU2: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 1283.260278] CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 1283.260279] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 1283.260283] CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 1283.260288] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 1283.260290] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[ 1283.260291] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[ 1283.261312] CPU3: Core temperature/speed normal
[ 1283.261314] CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 1283.261315] CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 1283.261316] CPU2: Core temperature/speed normal
[ 1283.261320] CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 1283.261323] CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
```

Having a fixed time interval (say 10 hours), how can I check **for how long have the CPUs been throttled**? What I need is to know each minute if the CPUs are being throttled. I guess I need to do a cron job for that, with some if/else condition.

OS: *Fedora 23 Workstation x86_64*

model: *HP ProBook 4730s (laptop)*

CPU: *Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2450M CPU @ 2.50GHz (family: 0x6, model: 0x2a, stepping: 0x7)*